# Angular get selected datalist object

Tags: angular

This `select` 1-way binding works

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation">
    <option *ngFor="let location of allLocationNames" [ngValue]="location">{{location.name}}</option>
</select>
```

`selectedLocation` will always contain the selected location **object**.

This `datalist` 1-way binding does not seem to work

```
<h4>Guest: <input type="text" name="guest" [(ngModel)]="selectedGuest" list="options">
  <datalist id=options *ngIf="allGuests">
    <option *ngFor="let guest of allGuests" [ngValue]="guest">{{guest.companyName}}</option>
  </datalist>
</h4>
```

`selectedGuest` will not contain an object but the string value (guest.companyName) of the selected element.

How can I get the selected object in the datalist example?

Answer (score 8):

I found workaround for this problem. You can use the following code :

```
 <input type="text" list="productList" name="product" [(ngModel)]='currentProduct' (change)="onProductChanged(currentProduct)" />
     <datalist id="productList">
       <select>
        <option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.name"></option>
       </select>
     </datalist>
```

And in typescript I wrote :

```
export class MySuperPrivateClass implements OnInit {
currentProduct: string = "";
selectedProduct: Product;

 onProductChanged(productName) {
    console.log(productName);
    this.selectedProduct = this.getSelectedProductByName(productName);
}

 getSelectedProductByName(selectedName: string): Product {
    return this.products.find(product => product.name === selectedName);
}
```

Comment: Did the job for me!

Comment: how to extract "key" attribute from option tag while still displaying the current value, considering key is different from value?

Comment: @DhruvSinghal sorry I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add data attribute to get the object or a property:

```
<option *ngFor="let guest of allGuests" data-guest="guest" [ngValue]="guest">
      {{guest.companyName}}</option>
```

and you can getting inside your component:

```
yourSelectedElement.data('guest')
```

Comment: I still get a string and not an object with this code

Comment: you need to get the value in your component on click event

Comment: check this https://derickbailey.com/2016/03/23/get-a-data-attribute-value-from-the-selected-datalist-option/

Comment: do you know how I can react to selecting an option in the datalist? Angular (click()=) doesn't seem to work within the datalist option tag

Comment: <datalist id=options *ngIf="allGuests" (change)="changeOption($event.target)">  you will have the selected option and can access your data

Comment: @FatehMohamed can please make plunker of your answer?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the input does not have the id attribute. For this to work you need to add the id attribute to the input and the name should be the same as the one of the datalist, please see the solution below:

```
<h4>Guest:
 <input type="text" id=options name="guest" [(ngModel)]="selectedGuest" list="options">

  <datalist id=options *ngIf="allGuests">
    <option *ngFor="let guest of allGuests" [ngValue]="guest">{{guest.companyName}}</option>
  </datalist>
</h4>
```