# How to add a search filter to a select option in angular

Tags: html, angular, multi-select, select-options

I'm trying to add to add a search filter in my select option list because there are many options and I think that without a search, it will not be easy for the user to find the option that he wants to select.

I hope you will understand me because I'm not good at English.

Here's my code (it's just a part of my table)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menaceProcessus of menaceProcessusTab">
    <tr>
         <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#f1f1f1"><b>{{menaceProcessus?.processus?.nom}}</b></td>
    </tr>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let actif of menaceProcessus?.actifs">
        <tr>
            <td [rowSpan]="actif?.menaces?.length+1">{{actif?.actif?.nom}}</td>
        </tr>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let mnVuln of actif?.menaces">
        <tr>
             <td>{{mnVuln?.vulnerabilite?.nom}}</td>
             <td>
                 <select class="form-control" 
                  (change)="mnVuln?.menaceActif?.menace.id = $event.target.value; 
                            updateMenaceProcessus()">
                      <option></option>
                      <option *ngFor="let menace of menaces" 
                          [value]="menace.id" 
                          [selected]="menace.id === mnVuln?.menaceActif?.menace.id">
                        {{menace.nom}}</option>
                  </select>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <input class="form-control" 
                    type="text" [value]="mnVuln?.menaceActif?.probabilite"> 
              </td>
          </tr>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: are you looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete

Comment: or use angular material's autocomplete: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: yeah i wan't to use angular material's autocomplete but i don't now how ! i'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter your array `menaces` by typing on the first letter, then it is possible to filter your array like this:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" 
     (change)="mnVuln?.menaceActif?.menace.id = $event.target.value; 
               updateMenaceProcessus();
               filterMenaces($event)">
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let menace of menaces" 
        [value]="menace.id" 
        [selected]="menace.id === mnVuln?.menaceActif?.menace.id">
        {{menace.nom}}</option>
</select>
```

TypeScript:

```
origMenaces = [];

methodAPIToGetMenaces() {
   this.yourService()
       .subscribe(s=> {
           this.menaces = s;
           this.origMenaces = s;
       });
}

filterMenaces(str: string) {
    if (typeof str === 'string') {
        this.menaces = this.origMenaces.filter(a => a.toLowerCase()
                                             .startsWith(str.toLowerCase())); 
    }
}
```

UPDATE 1:

If you want to filter by `input` value:

HTML:

```
<input type="text"         
    (ngModelChange)="filterItem($event)" 
    [(ngModel)]="filterText">
    <br>
<select 
     #selectList
     [(ngModel)]="myDropDown" 
    (ngModelChange)="onChangeofOptions($event)">
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of items">         
        {{item}}
    </option>    
</select>
<p>items {{ items | json }}</p>
```

TypeScript:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  myDropDown : string;
  items = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  origItems = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  @ViewChild('selectList', { static: false }) selectList: ElementRef;

  onChangeofOptions(newGov) {
     console.log(newGov);
  }

  filterItem(event){
      if(!event){
          this.items = this.origItems;
      } // when nothing has typed*/   
      if (typeof event === 'string') {
          console.log(event);
          this.items = this.origItems.filter(a => a.toLowerCase()
                                             .startsWith(event.toLowerCase())); 
      }
      console.log(this.items.length);
      this.selectList.nativeElement.size = this.items.length + 1 ;       
   }      
}
```

[Please, see work example at stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjf89w)

Comment: @PowerGirl Could you say exactly what doesn't work? I've tested and it works

Comment: the problem is here : `@ViewChild('selectList') selectList: ElementRef;` ! @ViewChild must have 2 parameters

Comment: @PowerGirl I've updated my answer. Please, see my updated answer. In addition, I've created an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjf89w

Comment: @PowerGirl  I am glad to help you!)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to filter in select option, you can use **datalist** control of HTML. If you use it, there is no need to do extra coding for filtering. It has built-in functionality for filtering.

HTML :

```
<input list="menace" name="menace">

<datalist id="menace">
     <option *ngFor="let menace of menaces">{{menace.nom}} </option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: what about the input value ?

Comment: Selected option will be displayed in input field. Yo can bind input with your selected value.

Comment: `<input list="menace" name="menace">
                                    <datalist id="menace" (change)="mnVuln?.menaceActif?.menace.id = $event.target.value; updateMenaceProcessus()">
                                        <option *ngFor="let menace of menaces" [selected]="menace.id === mnVuln?.menaceActif?.menace.id">{{menace.nom}} </option>
                                    </datalist>` this  is what i tried to  do but it doesn't work

Comment: To bind datalist follow this link of stackoverflow [bind datalist and get object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50840917/11685310)

Comment: I think it is a correct answer but with a very simple UI and hard to modify so as to be of practical use on something beyond a pet project.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use ng-select: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select
for Yor Requirement

Comment: Thank you ! i'll take a look

Comment: Perfect! thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any easy way to do this for the select, but the autocomplete
component seems to do something very close to what is desired. The only issue with it is, that it does not require the value to be one of the options. That's why I created the following directive:

```js
// mat-autocomplete-force-select.directive.ts
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors, Validator } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatAutocomplete } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

@Directive({
  selector: '[matAutocomplete][appMatAutocompleteForceSelect]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: MatAutocompleteForceSelectDirective,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class MatAutocompleteForceSelectDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('matAutocomplete')
  matAutocomplete!: MatAutocomplete;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (this.matAutocomplete.options && !this.isOptionOfAutocomplete(control.value)) {
      return { 'notAnAutocompleteValue' : true }
    }

    return null;
  }

  private isOptionOfAutocomplete(value: string) {
    return this.matAutocomplete.options.find(option => option.value === value) !== undefined;
  }
}
```

After that, you can add the directive to the input of the autocomplete, and it will have an error of `notAnAutocompleteValue` if it's not that.

```html
<input matInput type="text" appMatAutocompleteForceSelect [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-autocomplete>
```

For anyone unfamiliar with the autocomplete component, https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview will be helpful.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input list="menace" name="menace">
<datalist id="menace">
 <option *ngFor="let menace of menaces">{{menace.nom}} </option>
</datalist>
```

This works fine and in the case of a form just add a form control name and the value can be picked. Answered by @ParthDhankecha