# Angular 2 - How to filter through a select

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having trouble with this code which is Angular 2. I have something like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="postoSelecionado" name="postos-disponiveis" id="postos-disponiveis" class="sel-posto" materialize="material_select" [disabled]="!checkboxPostos.checked">
      <option *ngFor="let posto of getPostosAtivos" [value]="posto?.cdPt">{{ posto?.cdPt}}&mdash;{{ posto?.dsPt }}</option>
</select>
```

And I want to search through this select. I'm really struggling with this. Can we do something like a search like in the example below?

```
 <option *ngFor="let posto of getPostosAtivos | search:postoSelecionado" [value]="posto?.cdPt">{{ posto?.cdPt}}&mdash;{{ posto?.dsPt }}</option>
```

Comment: What is it that should trigger a change in `getPostosAtivos`? Do you have multiple `select`? You can use a pipe like you've already suggested, but there are more efficient methods.

Comment: @DanielB The trigger should be the moment the user types something. He's looking for an item but the select list is too long so I want to give him the alternative to search.

Comment: Hey @Daniel B , Im still having a hard time on this, I tried what Janith said but unfortunally, it's not working properly. Is there anyway I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use suitable npm packages matching with your requirement like ng-select: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select for your Requirement

Or you can create your own select option.

Please check this also
[How to add a search filter to a select option in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625699/how-to-add-a-search-filter-to-a-select-option-in-angular)

Comment: Thank You. I tried harder and manage to do it with ng-select. I just had to downgrade my ng-select version to the same version of the Angular I'm using.