# How to get other values of a selected value in Angular 10

Tags: arrays, angular, for-loop, html-select, key-value

I have an array:

```
export const Glcode = [
    { id: 1, Type: 'Asset', Name: 'Cash at Head Office', code: '10018' },
    { id: 2, Type: 'Asset', Name: 'POS ACCOUNT ', code: '10432' },
    { id: 3, Type: 'Asset', Name: 'Cash With Bank', code: '10433'},
    { id: 4, Type: 'Custom', Name: 'Cash With Bank ', code: '10436'},
]
```

And my HTML code has a select tag:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="gl-code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">GL Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" style="margin-left: 25px;" placeholder="Enter the GL name" class="form-control"
           data-min-length="1"
           name="journal.glname" [(ngModel)]="journal.glname" (input)="filterNumber()" list="glcode"
           data-relatives='#chained_relative' data-chained-relatives='true' (change)="selectGL($event.value)">

    <datalist id="glcode">
      <option *ngFor="let i of glcode" [value]="i.Name">{{i.Name}}</option>
    </datalist>
  </div>

  <label for="gl-code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">GL Type:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <div
      list="glcode">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label style="margin-left: -13px;" for="gl-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">GL Number:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="glname" name="glname"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<label for="gl-code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">GL Type:</label>
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
  <div
    list="glcode">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label style="margin-left: -13px;" for="gl-name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">GL Number:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="glname" name="glname"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my TypeScript code:

```
glcode = Glcode
btnDisabled = false;

selectGL(data){
  console.log(this.glcode[data].code) 
}
```

I would like to automatically set it that if I select one `glcode.Name`, the corresponding `glcode.Type` and `glcode.code` will show automatically.
For example if I select 'POS ACCOUNT' in the drop down list/ select options, `10432` and `Asset` will show under GL Number and GL Type label respectively
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220448/angular-get-selected-datalist-object

Answer (score 0):

You mention a dropdown in your question but there isn't one in the HTML that you posted?

But if you want fields to auto populate when selecting an item from a dropdown, you would do this by using an *ngFor to loop through your items for your dropdown and then ngModel to bind the selected item from the dropdown to a variable (which I will refer to as selectedItem) and then you setup your fields to be linked to the fields of selectedItem for example:

```
 <label for="gl-code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">GL Type:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <div 
               list="glcode" > {{selectedItem.glCode}}
            </div>
```

You will have to put in nullchecks to make sure that nothing breaks, but this should help you.